# How can I scan all connected USB drives for a file?

Tags: usb, bash, scripts, python, perl

I have an install of Ubuntu and I would like to run a script (bash, perl, python, whatever) that will scan all connected USB drives and report if it finds a text file.  Could anyone guide me on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The way I personally approach this would be `for` loop with `find` command, supplying the directories where drives are mounted

```
for DRIVE in "/media/username/Drive1" "/media/username/Drive2" "/mnt";
do
  find "$DRIVE" -type f -name "myFile.txt"
done
```

Simpler way would be just supply the directories without for loop

```
  find "/media/username/Drive1" "/media/username/Drive2" "/mnt" -type f -name "myFile.txt"
```

Comment: I apologize if this is a really newbie question, but I won't know the drive labels ahead of time - in other words, someone could plug the drive in any of 6 ports on the computer.  I need to enumerate all possible connected drives, names unknown, and then loop through them all.

Comment: Btw, I am running Ubuntu server, not desktop, so this is all at the shell.  Does the system automount?  Sorry about the silly questions, I am a Windows guy so the Linux environment is still a bit new to me.  In other words, can I just plug in a USB drive and they show up in /media? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll expand the script, I am confident it can be possible to parse output udisksctl, but as for automount, i am not 100% sure as I've not touched server. In desktop, unity amd gnome interface with udisksctl for that

Comment: That would be awesome.  I can look up mounting and see what I can figure out...

Comment: Serg, just thought I'd letcha know that I figured out how to do it.  I installed the usbmount package which automounts drives to /media/usb[0-7].  Then I took your  idea of the for loop and looped through all the drives and searched for my text file.  This seems to work well so far.  Thanks for your help!